# QlikView: Can a SQL query be used in Expression of a List Box?

Tags: qlikview

I would like to create a List box which accepts an SQL query as an expression. Is it possible in QlikView?

For example, if I would like to display the Avg(sal) of all employees reporting to one Manager.
So, basically, list box should have the names of Managers and by selecting the manager, the average of sal can be viewed. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you have a self referencing column in a table things can get dicey. To do this in Qlikview, the best solution is to create a managers table in the Qlikview script:

```
employees:
LOAD * INLINE [
    empnum, empname, man_empnum, salary
    1, Bill, 2, 50000
    2, John, 3, 75000
    3, Mary, , 115000
    4, Mike, 2, 45000
    5, Amy, 2, 58000
];

managers:
load distinct(man_empnum)
resident employees;

inner join(managers)
load empnum as man_empnum,
     empname as manname 
resident employees;
```

This grabs a distinct list of only the manager employee numbers contained in the `man_empnum` field and then joins the appropriate employee name to each record. Only employees referenced as managers will show up in the managers table.

Once you have this in place you just need to create your list box. Grab the `manname` field from your "Select Fields" dialog, and then add `min({1}man_empnum)` in the Expressions tab. As I had previously mentioned in my old answer, you can add expressions to any list box with this procedure. Using `min()` in this case is just to ensure that the manager's employee number is always displayed in the list box. You'll see if you simply use `man_empnum` as the expression, the list box will only display the employee number of the selected manager. The important part is getting access to the set selector `{1}` so you can use any aggregation function you'd like in place of `min`. As long as you only ever have one employee number per employee, this will work.

Comment: Sorry for not adding full details. Lets say I have a table with EMPLOYEE details such as EMPNO,EMPNAME,MANAGER,SALARY. However, the MANAGER is not a name but an EMPNO who is in turn an EMPLOYEE in that table. So, basically there is a Hierarchy between Manager & Empno. In this scenario:                       1.I wanted to write an SQL query which gets list of MANAGER NAMES (EMPNAME) & EMPNO (i.e., EMPNO of each MANAGER) .       2.Now use that query as an input to a LIST BOX. Is this achievable ?

Comment: One other note, assuming all your employees are entered into your employees table, as long as it's hierarchical, there will always be at least one employee at the top who has no manager. In my example, Mary is at the top and therefore has no reference to a manager.

Comment: I am able to get the required output  only in 'Table box ' format. When I am trying to create a 'bar chart' or a 'Pie-chart',  with Dimension as "manname" & expression as '"avg(sal)", I see 'no data to display'. Can you please suggest if I am doing anything wrong here?

Comment: I've [uploaded a .qvw for you to check out](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7pnF70BI32KeXlVSTNLdDJmeVE/view?usp=sharing).You should be able to access it if you have a license. If you are using the free personal edition you won't, in which case, try this formula in your expression: `avg({1}aggr(avg({1}salary), empname))`.